# MySQL how do I only show the max/highest values with the following query?

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have the following tables:

```
mysql> select * from F_FINDINGS;
+---------+------------+
|   F_ID  | CONFIDENCE |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |        100 | 
|       2 |         70 | 
|       2 |       0.35 | 
|       1 |        100 | 
+---------+------------+

mysql> select * from F_THINGS;
+---------+-------------------+--------+------------+
|   F_ID  |    F_TITLE        |  S_ID  | F_VALUE    |
+---------+-------------------+--------+------------+
|       1 | STUFF A           |      1 |        1.1 |       
|       2 | STUFF C           |      1 |      202.2 | 
|       3 | OBJECT P          |      1 |       10.7 |           
|       4 | Things X          |      2 |        540 |   
|       5 | STUFF D           |      2 |       1080 | 
|       6 | OBJECT M          |      2 |        455 |       
|       7 | Things A          |      3 |        333 |              
|       8 | Things B          |      4 |        825 |         
|       9 | STUFF A           |      1 |      103.4 |          
|      10 | STUFF A           |      1 |       98.4 |
+---------+-------------------+--------+------------+

  mysql> select * from DUMP;
   +--------+----------+
   | D_ID   | D_NAME   |
   +--------+----------+
   |      1 |   E0     | 
   |      2 |   A1     | 
   |      3 |   AB     | 
   +--------+----------+

mysql> select * FROM STUFF;
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|   S_ID |   D_ID |   S_TITLE         |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|      1 |      1 | plastic           | 
|      2 |      2 | metal             | 
|      3 |      3 | wood              | 
|      4 |      3 | gel               | 
+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

I'm using the following query

```
SELECT
d.D_NAME,
s.S_TITLE,
f.F_VALUE,
IF(r.CONFIDENCE IS NULL, 'N/A', CONCAT((r.CONFIDENCE),'%')AS CONFIDENCE

FROM F_THINGS f

JOIN STUFF s ON s.S_ID=f.S_ID
JOIN DUMP d on d.D_ID=s.D_ID

LEFT JOIN F_FINDINGS r ON f.F_ID=r.F_ID;
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| D_NAME   | S_TITLE   | F_VALUE    | CONFIDENCE |
+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| E0       |  plastic  |      202.2 | 70%        |  
| E0       |  plastic  |       10.7 | N/A        |
| E0       |  plastic  |        1.1 | 100%       |  
| A1       |  metal    |        540 | N/A        | 
| A1       |  metal    |       1080 | N/A        | 
| A1       |  metal    |        455 | N/A        | 
| AB       |  wood     |        333 | N/A        | 
| AB       |  wood     |        825 | N/A        | 
| E0       |  gel      |      103.4 | N/A        | 
| E0       |  gel      |       98.4 | N/A        | 
+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

**I only want the highest value shown for each**

Comment: Where's your "STUFF" sample data...  Also, highest value? or highest Confidence?  just making sure

Comment: @DRapp i'll add 'stuff' Table. Sorry I left that out. I want highest confidence

Comment: @VAShhh Desired output is listed at the very bottom where it says 'Desired Results'

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your desired output.  If you want the highest confidence... highest per what... D_Name, S_Title?  You are showing 3, 3, 2, 2 entries.  Ex: Do you only want to see the "E0 - plastic - 1.1 of 100%" even though the other "E0 - plastic - 202.2 at 70%" ?

Comment: @DRapp if you look at F_FINDINGS table. I want to display only Highest confidence for an F_ID (from the F_FINDINGS table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, however there are no values in STUFF that would give your desired result ('gel' and 'plastic' will need the same S_ID and D_ID, and still be different somehow) which makes the result slightly different from your desired one. Next time you may want to add STUFF so no one has to reverse engineer it ;-)

```
SELECT
d.D_NAME,
s.S_TITLE,
f.F_VALUE,
IF(MAX(r.CONFIDENCE) IS NULL, 'N/A', CONCAT((MAX(r.CONFIDENCE)),'%')) AS CONFIDENCE
FROM F_THINGS f
JOIN STUFF s ON s.S_ID=f.S_ID
JOIN DUMP d on d.D_ID=s.D_ID
LEFT JOIN F_FINDINGS r ON f.F_ID=r.F_ID
GROUP BY D_NAME, S_TITLE, F_VALUE;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48667/5).

Also added a demo with the values in F_THINGS corrected (different S_ID for lines you want grouped with gel and plastic) to make the grouping you're requiring possible [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da13/2).

Comment: I may not be totally understanding a fundamental aspect of "group by" but why does it only display the highest? (which after all is what I was after)

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it A group consists of rows with the same D_NAME, S_TITLE and F_VALUE. The MAX on confidence will show the highest in each group.

Answer (score 1):

try...

ORDER BY confidence DESC

as the last line of your query

Comment: I only want the highest value shown for each. Order by will display all

Comment: How about: `ORDER BY confidence DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: maybe combine this with a group by clause then

Answer (score 0):

Then just change your

```
LEFT JOIN F_FINDINGS r ON f.F_ID=r.F_ID;
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN ( select F_ID, MAX(  CONFIDENCE ) as Confidence
               from F_Findings
               group by F_ID ) as r
   on F.F_ID = r.F_ID
```